# Semantic-Release doesn't create release with BREAKING CHANGE

Tags: javascript, node.js, semantic-release

When I create a commit like this, `git commit -m'BREAKING CHANGE: foo bar'` and push up `semantic-release` tells me,

```
[@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: BREAKING CHANGE: Changes from slice_into_subrepo
[@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 1 commits complete: no release
```

How come `BREAKING CHANGE` doesn't create a release, it's [documented to do that here](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release),

> BREAKING CHANGE: The graphiteWidth option has been removed.
> The default graphite width of 10mm is always used for performance reasons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is a really poor error.** The reason why is [reported in GitHub issue #108](https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer/issues/108),

> Please see the Angular Commit Message Conventions. `BREAKING CHANGE`: must be in the footer of the commit. You wrote it in the subject.

This may be confusing because the example on the home page shows,

```
perf(pencil): remove graphiteWidth option

BREAKING CHANGE: The graphiteWidth option has been removed.
The default graphite width of 10mm is always used for performance reasons.
```

**This is not two examples, it's one.** This is how it looks to have "BREAKING CHANGE:" in the footer.

This is also [touched on on the documentation for `@semantic-release/commit-analyzer`,](https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer/)

> Note: Your commits must be formatted exactly as specified by the chosen convention. For example the Angular Commit Message Conventions require the `BREAKING CHANGE` keyword to be followed by a colon (`:`) and to be in the **footer of the commit message.**

For more information see the upsream docs on [*"Angular Commit Message Format"*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-commit-message-format)

Comment: OMG I just ran into this problem. What the heck is a "footer" in commit message? I have no idea a commit message can have subject and footer differences. :(

Comment: Also worth mentioning that only the following commit types will make a release:
- fix
- feat
- perf

All others WON'T publish a release. You can however tweak the configuration to make it work

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get this work you will have to add this to your config releaseRules:

```
    '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
    {
      preset: 'conventionalcommits',
      releaseRules: [
        { breaking: true, release: 'major' },
```

There are several issues related to this, and this is the only thing that worked for me. Here's my answer on [issue-2765](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/2756)